# W/PicturePileLayerContent﹕ Warning: painting PicturePile without content

Tags: android, admob

i am getting this warning in logcat, I searched the web but didn't get what's the reason or how should i deal with it? what does that indicate?

here is the logcat there is nothing else in logcat that is unusual

```
02-23 15:17:52.190  29817-30304/com.astrolabe.iremote W/PicturePileLayerContent﹕     Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
02-23 15:17:52.190  29817-30304/com.astrolabe.iremote W/PicturePileLayerContent﹕ Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
02-23 15:17:52.190  29817-30304/com.astrolabe.iremote W/PicturePileLayerContent﹕ Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
02-23 15:17:52.190  29817-30304/com.astrolabe.iremote W/PicturePileLayerContent﹕ Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
02-23 15:17:53.190  29817-30304/com.astrolabe.iremote W/PicturePileLayerContent﹕ Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
```

Comment: Do you perchance have AdMob installed?

Comment: Any updates on that? I get that too...

Answer (score 5):

You can simply ignore this warning or even errors because they're related to admob sdk