# Loading image url into webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-websettings

I'm trying to load image into a webview from http://loremflickr.com/ , but it doesn't seem to work on android 4.3 . Can anyone explain to me why and how can i fix this ? 
it work fine for Android 4.4 and Android 5 but not 4.3

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadUrlInWebView("http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog");
}
private void loadUrlInWebView(String _URL) {
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewer);
    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl(_URL);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.e("TAG", "error code " + errorCode);
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
///logcat 
09-30 14:32:33.387    4309-4309/com.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-30 14:32:35.395    4309-4309/com.myapplication D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
09-30 14:32:35.582    4309-4309/com.myapplication D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
09-30 14:32:35.621    4309-4309/com.myapplication D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
09-30 14:32:36.035    4309-4309/com.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-30 14:32:36.199    4309-4309/com.myapplication D/TAG﹕ onLoadResource http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog
09-30 14:32:37.246    4309-4309/com.myapplication D/TilesManager﹕ Starting TG #0, 0x59fe9ae8
09-30 14:32:37.246    4309-4309/com.myapplication D/TilesManager﹕ new EGLContext from framework: 59ebc0c0
09-30 14:32:37.246    4309-4309/com.myapplication D/GLWebViewState﹕ Reinit shader
09-30 14:32:37.262    4309-4309/com.myapplication D/GLWebViewState﹕ Reinit transferQueue
09-30 14:32:37.317    4309-4398/com.myapplication W/PicturePileLayerContent﹕ Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
09-30 14:32:37.324    4309-4398/com.myapplication W/PicturePileLayerContent﹕ Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
09-30 14:32:37.324    4309-4398/com.myapplication W/PicturePileLayerContent﹕ Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
```

Comment: i tryed that but its not work

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: getting same error under 19 devices .white screen .Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967578/w-picturepilelayercontent-warning-painting-picturepile-without-content

Answer (score 1):

### Whats your mistake:

Don't use

```
loadUrlInWebView("http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog");
```

Use

```
loadUrl("http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog");
```

**Finally**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadUrlInWebView();
}
private void loadUrlInWebView() {
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewer);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog");
    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort (true);

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.e("TAG", "error code " + errorCode);
    }
}
```

For details:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: @SalahHammouda Can you post logcat please

Comment: @SalahHammouda I watched .Wait

Comment: @SalahHammouda Its not your coding fault .Its admob related .Under 19 api suffer from this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewer);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog");
```

Just  load image by this, it will definitely work.